# How do you build a string from outputs of a process in Nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

Let's say I have a process in Nextflow that has two outputs, like this

```
process FB_PROCESS {
    output:
    path "foo*.txt", emit: foo_file
    path "bar*.txt", emit: bar_file

    """
    echo Hello > foo---Man---.txt
    echo Hello > bar---355---.txt
    """
}
```

In this case the two outputs will be `foo---Man---.txt` and `bar---355---.txt`

Furthermore, let's say there existed a bunch of files in a folder on my computer called /path/to/Man/bar.

What I want to do, but do not know how to do, is glob for all those files and submit them to run in parallel to another process.

If I were to recklessly mix nextflow and python, this how I would build a channel `my_channel = Channel.fromPath(f'/path/to/{FB_PROCESS.out.foo_file.split("---")[1]}/{FB_PROCESS.out.bar_file.split("---")[1]}/*')`

Obviously, that is not the correct syntax to do what I want do do. How do I properly build that glob string in Nextflow?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that there's no easy way to pull a value out of a channel, which would be what's required to construct the glob pattern (and create another channel). I think the solution here is to just feed in all the files, and then filter for the ones you want. You could construct a key from the filenames of the process outputs and use the [`combine`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine) operator to select the files with a matching key. For example:

```
params.input_files = '/path/to/*/*/*'
```

```
process FB_PROCESS {

    output:
    path "foo---Man---.txt", emit: foo_file
    path "bar---355---.txt", emit: bar_file

    """
    touch foo---Man---.txt
    touch bar---355---.txt
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    (foo, bar) = FB_PROCESS()

    foo_id = foo.map { it.name.split('---')[1] }
    bar_id = bar.map { it.name.split('---')[0] }

    key = foo_id.concat( bar_id ).toList()

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.input_files )
        .map { file ->

            def foo_id = file.parent.parent.name
            def bar_id = file.parent.name

            tuple( foo_id, bar_id, file )
        }
        .combine( key, by: [0,1] )
        .map { foo_id, bar_id, file -> file }
        .view()

}
```

Testing:

```
$ mkdir -p /path/to/{Man,Foo,Bar}/{foo,bar,baz}
$ touch /path/to/{Man,Foo,Bar}/{foo,bar,baz}/{A,B,C}.txt
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [prickly_bardeen] DSL2 - revision: f56bf583ef
executor >  local (1)
[71/25e07b] process > FB_PROCESS [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
/path/to/Man/bar/A.txt
/path/to/Man/bar/B.txt
/path/to/Man/bar/C.txt
```

Comment: This is so detailed and makes really good sense. Thank you for taking the time on this. 

I don't believe it is ideal for my purposes for two reasons
1) The number of files in '/path/to/*/*/*' is sizeable and growing
2) The files of interest don't actually exist when the pipeline is kicked off. They are made in the course of the pipeline.

I think I'm going to take a different approach altogether where I do the parallelize within a subsequent process rather than trying to parallelize by using a channel with all the files.

Still though, super educational. I learned a lot from answer.

Comment: I've just got one more follow-up question: Is it possible to construct Channel.fromPath('/to/path/*/*/*') in the middle of the workflow instead of at the outset?

Comment: @Avery85 No worries at all - you said that the files are made in the course of the pipeline. Do you mean that one or more of your processes writes to files outside of the working directory (i.e. `./work`)? Usually you want to avoid this to ensure that your pipeline is portable. You can create channels using any of the factory methods (like `fromPath`) anywhere in your code, but I suspect a different approach is needed here. Happy to make some suggestions if you can describe what you're trying to do.